# Regex Only Match Normal Chars Plus Accent

Tags: .net, regex

Below is the current match.
It is matching all forms of characters like with the double dots above.
What is the term for the other forms of a character?
I only want a-z, A-Z, and accented a-z.
What is the proper Regex for that?

```
(?:[-_'@\w]+)
```

Comment: Which accents do you want to allow? Just the acute (á) and grave (à) accents, or do you also want to allow circumflex (â), tilde (ã), diaeresis (ä), ring (å), caron (š), etc.? And why do you want to allow accented a-z, but not accented A-Z? Why not other Latin-alphabet letters (e.g. ç, Ð, ñ, ø, Þ, æ, œ, ß)? Why not Cyrillic letters or other alphabets?

Comment: @JoeWhite Great comment.  What I want is characters that commonly occur in US. What I meant is acute (á) - I am learning.  And there is not a perfect answer.  How do I start with just straight chars and add just one special form and I can take it from there.  I am parsing files that can be anything and need to limit it to words that have a good chance of being a real word in US.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you're just trying to match words commonly used in English, you're still going to miss some this way. For example, poetic accents ("a very learnèd man") use [grave accents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent), not the acute accents you're asking for. English is also notorious for stealing words from other languages, like vis-à-vis, El Niño, façade. You'll have a hard time with some names, e.g. Chloë, as well as with the occasional person who uses traditional spellings like coöperate (I've seen that sort of spelling more than once in technical blogs, where people tend to be sticklers for uncommon detail).

So what you're asking for is not generally useful, and for that reason, you're extremely unlikely to find something pre-built to do it. You'll just have to do the work yourself. Write a regex that matches ASCII `A-Z` and `a-z`, and then manually list all the others you want.

```
(?:[-_'@A-Za-záéíóúý]+)
```

Comment: I did not expected something pre-built.

Answer (score 1):

Use Unicode Category or Unicode Block:

```
\p{L}+
```

`\p{L}` stands for all letter characters.

Comment: Not correct. Specifically stated NO match on character with doubles dots above.  That matches Regex.IsMatch("Ä", @"\p{L}+").